# How not to overwrite your variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stuck on this problem without a clear way around it for a while now. https://jsfiddle.net/brendanjackson/4ajs7czo/3/

Here's the scenario. I have two functions that send one set of data to different areas of my page. So if you enter some text in the main field, hit submit, it sends that text to 'set1' and creates a button and select menu.

```
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">



    <div class="start">  
        <form class="form-inline">

          <h1><strong>Start</strong></h1>
    <div class="row">        
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              Task:<input type="text" class= "task form-control" id="input_text" > 
            </div>
      </div>
  <!--***********************************************************************************************************-->
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            Send to:
            <select class="set1_menu">
              <option value="set1table0">set1table0</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="button" id='submit_button' class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit!" />
          </div>

        </div>

        </form>
    </div>
  <!--***********************************************************************************************************-->


      <div>

       <h1 class="label label-default">Set1</h1>

        <div class="set1 row">

          <div class="set1_table0 column ">
            <h3>set1table0</h3>
            <ul class="set1_text0"></ul>
          </div>


    </div>

<!--**********************************************************************************************************--> 
      <div>

        <h1 class="label label-default set2">Set2</h1>

      </div>
<!--*********************************************************************************************************-->
    <div>


        <div class="set2_table0 column">
          <h3>set2table0</h3>
          <ul class="set2_text0"></ul>
        </div>


    </div>


    </div>


  $('#submit_button').on("click",function() {    

    /*==========================================
                      variabes
    ===========================================*/
      task = $(".task").val();
        set1_menu = $(".set1_menu option:selected");
      set1_index = set1_menu.index() //switch arg

      set2_menu = '<select class="set2_menu"> <option value="set2_table0">set2table0</option> </select>';
      set2_button = '<input type="button" class="set2_button" data-set1_data="'+set1_index+'"  value="set2_button" />'

$('.set1_table0').append("<li>" + task + " "  + set2_menu + " " + set2_button + "</li>" );


  })

  $("div.set1.row").on("click", "input.set2_button", function(){
      /*==========================================
                        variabes
      ===========================================*/

      var set2_index = $(this).closest('li').find('select.set2_menu option:selected').index();
      var set1_data = $(this).data('set1_data');
      var set2_data = $(this).data('set2_data');

      /*=========================================
                        TEST
      =========================================*/
      console.log( "IT WORKS" + " " + set2_index );

   switch(set2_index){
        case 0:
        $('.set2_table0').append("<li>" + task + " "  + " (from Table " +set1_data+ "  )" + " " /*+ datetimepicker + " "*/  + "</li>" );
        break;

    }

  });
```

**Problem:**

If the user follows the data sent to set1 and sends it to set2 all is well and the jedi win!

However, if the user decides to go back to the start, enter new information, and send it to set1, the previous variable has of course been overwritten and can no longer be sent to set2. It will now send whatever the newest variable's information is.

Something was suggested to me like adding `var i=0++, task` and then adding `i++` on my 1st function so it gives each variable its own easy to find # like task0, task1, task(n) as well as turning it into an array. Both of these solutions I'm just not understanding how to implement, maybe for the lack of how to express my problem to research it?

**Question**

How do I cleanly save each set of data that is submitted so that it can be sent from set1 to set2 whenever the user decides they're ready.

Comment: Your structure is inconsistent, which isn't going to help - for example the set1 heading, `<h1 class="label label-default">Set1</h1>` stands on its own but set2 `<h1 class="label label-default set2">Set2</h1>` is enclosed in a `<div/>`. It's not malformed, but inconsistency will just make things more difficult.  Your fiddle is also missing a close-div `</div>` for container-fluid and the close body tag. (fiddle can just omit the body tag anyway)

Comment: Rushed through the simplified version looks like. Do you have a solution for the question?